# Windows 10 “Some settings are managed by your organization” (gpedit.msc does not work)

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, start-menu

I am using Windows 10 Pro. Suddenly I see a strange warning "Some Settings Are Managed By Your Organization."

I **Googled** it and found a solution something like this :

> In the Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc), go to Computer
>   Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Data
>   Collection and Preview Builds.
>
> Find the Allow Telemetry item and double-click it to edit the
>   policies.
>
> Change the setting to Enabled. Change the drop-down menu entry to
>   3-Full and click Apply.
>
> Now open the item again and change its Setting to Not configured and
>   hit the Save button.

Somehow this is not working in my case, I want to change my start menu but Windows won't allow me being an Admin to the PC.

[image: It looks like this]

Comment: is this device connected to a corporate network or is it for your personal use?

Comment: No its for Personal Use @MustafaAKTAŞ

Comment: Though I am connected to My office network but there are no such policy to control settings for Windows users @MustafaAKTAŞ

Answer (score 1):

The message you see within your settings that says `Some settings are managed by your organization` is true, but your Google search led you to the wrong Group Policy.  You want to scrutinize these:

`Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Start Menu and Taskbar`

`User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Start Menu and Taskbar`

Within each of those, ensure that the `Start Layout` policy is set to `Not Configured`.  After you modify those Group Policies, you should be able to change your start menu.

You can potentially make the same changes within the `Registry Editor` by doing the following:

1. Press <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
2. Type `regedit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (and acknowledge the UAC prompt, if necessary)
3. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer`
4. Right-click the the DWORD titled `LockedStartLayout` and select **Delete**
5. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer`
6. Right-click the the DWORD titled `LockedStartLayout` and select **Delete**
7. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`
8. Right-click the the DWORD titled `NoChangeStartMenu` and select **Delete**
9. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`
10. Right-click the the DWORD titled `NoChangeStartMenu` and select **Delete**
11. Close the `Registry Editor`
12. Reboot the computer

([Source](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/pin-to-start-missing-windows/))

Comment: @ruk5k i just did this, but still not working, do i need a reboot ? of safemode to do this ?

Comment: @ruk5k i just did this, but still not working, do i need a reboot ? of safemode to do this ?

Comment: Can you please open cmd and type rsop and tell us if there is any policy ?

Comment: You shouldn't necessarily need a reboot... it should take effect several seconds after the change.  Please keep in mind that on a Windows domain, Local Group Policy has the lowest processing priority.  As a result, if there are Domain Group Policies that affect the Start Menu, they will take precedence over the modifications that we just made.  You may want to check with your Domain Admin staff and you can [use utilities to check which Group Policies are affecting your login](http://www.howtogeek.com/116184/how-to-see-which-group-policies-are-applied-to-your-pc-and-user-account/).

Comment: None of these keys exist after the Anniversary update

Comment: @cat, when you have a few minutes to spare, please take a look at the source article that I referenced at the end of my answer.  It provides some additional perspective regarding this scenario, and was written after the Anniversary Update (version 1607) was released.  Ultimately, those registry keys don't actually appear unless one of the corresponding group policies has been implemented on that machine.  I don't have them on my Windows 10 computers, either.