# Administration rights lost

Tags: windows-10, administrator

I appear to no longer be an administrator. When I try to change anything I get the message "...is managed by your system administrator".

Can anyone help me get my status back?

(I'm using win10).

Comment: This message is based on policies, not being an administrator. If your computer is not part of a domain, your profile is corrupted.

Comment: @LPChip, while that is good advice, I configure Local Group Policies on my Windows 10 Pro machines utilizing `gpedit.msc`.  As a result, an end-user would see the same message without their profile being corrupted.  The same principle would apply if the equivalent registry entries were updated.

Comment: Mikeh, what is your goal?  What are you *not* able to do?  There are a few good questions that you can reference with similar scenarios like [this one](http://superuser.com/q/1160213/650163) and [this one](http://superuser.com/q/947755/650163).

Comment: @Run5k Yes I am aware. But if Mikeh was managing his policies, wouldn't he be able to understand that this message comes from his own tweaking? For that reason, I ruled out that its something he did himself. But true, it is possible to manage local group policies and get the same effect. I guess malware could also do this.

Comment: Thanks to LPChip and Run5k. I have lost my desktop gadgets, and when I try to recover them I get the stated message (DT Gadgets are managed by your system administrator). I have tried to enter gpedit.msc, but get the message "Windows cannot find gpedit.msc.

Comment: If you can't find `gpedit.msc` on your system, I assume you are utilizing Windows 10 Home (versus Pro). As a result, the Local Group Policy interface isn't available. That being said, what do you mean when you say you *"lost (your) desktop gadgets?"* Were you using third-party software, or are you referring to the live tiles?  Microsoft actually retired the use of desktop gadgets long before Windows 10 was released:  [Where can I enable the Desktop Gadgets in Window 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/948067/where-can-i-enable-the-desktop-gadgets-in-window-10)

Comment: If this *is* a case of your Windows 10 [Live Tiles](https://www.howtogeek.com/223254/how-to-add-remove-and-customize-tiles-on-the-windows-10-start-menu/) being locked-down, you should be able to resolve it based upon my answer within this question:  [Windows 10 Some Settings are managed by your administrator gpedit.msc does not work](http://superuser.com/a/1160249/650163)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 “Some settings are managed by your organization” (gpedit.msc does not work)](https://superuser.com/questions/1160213/windows-10-some-settings-are-managed-by-your-organization-gpedit-msc-does-not)